# Angular 6 rxjs 6 return Observable nested element

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

I would like to return a child element of an observable as this.

Say I have a HttpClient that gets an observable of people:

```
export class People{

    public Name: string;
}
```

and a service that gets a single one as abservable:

```
public get(id: number): Observable<People> {
    return this.http.get<People>('http://localhost:8801/' + "people/" + id);
  }
```

Now I would like to get the name from my observable as observable:

```
public get(id: number): Observable<string>{
    this.peopleService.get(id) .... ?
}
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) function to transform people observable:

```
const nameObservable = this.peopleService.get(id).pipe(
    map(people => people.name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

subscribe to the event

```
  this.peopleService.get(id).subscribe((item) => {
   console.log(item.name)
 })
```

Comment: No I don't want to get the name I want to return the name as a Observable<string>. In  specific I would like to bind async to the name property.